How to change android app id in project idx?
So I want to connect two of my apps to firebase and i can't seem to figure out how can I change my android id as by default it's com.example.myapp for both of my apps.
I tried renaming it in build.gradle but it doesn't seem to work or am I missing something?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can use the package change_app_package_name: ^1.3.0 to change your app's package name. Add this package to your pubspec.yaml, then run the command dart run change_app_package_name:main com.your_package_name. It will automatically update your package name everywhere.

It worked thank you so much I was stuck for a while :)

@RayeesAmin consider accepting this answer so others can know what works. Thank you :)

I just searched in all files for "com.example" and found these in a new IDX Flutter project:
/home/user/myapp/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/myapp/MainActivity.kt
  1,9: package com.example.myapp

/home/user/myapp/android/app/build.gradle
  27,18:     namespace = "com.example.myapp"
  38,26:         applicationId = "com.example.myapp"

I presume if you edit those to your desired ID, if would suffice.
